# Application closed - JNI Local Reference

Tags: android, cordova, java-native-interface

I have created application using android phonegap.when  I am using application continously i am getting the error **JNI Local Reference table overflow(max=512).** So I searched and tried some sample for accessing JNI from android and developed the sample application for adding two numbers using JNI.Now I need to know how to delete the local reference table in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to release the local references after use immediately:

```
// get string
jstring str = env->NewStringUTF(text);
// do something
env->CallVoidMethod(currentCallingObject, MID_Activity_print, str);
// release reference
env->DeleteLocalRef(str);
```

Comment: How to i know which local reference used in my app.My doubt is : In NewStringUTF(text) - what is text? it is local reference or any other else.If the text is local reference,how to get local reference from app for deleting

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242 and 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local and

Comment: Hi,I can't understand.I just want a sample method for getting local reference used by app and delete that reference using JNI.please guide me